# TfidfVectorizer: ValueError: not a built-in stop list: russian

Tags: python, tf-idf

I try to apply TfidfVectorizer with russian stop words

```
Tfidf = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='russian' )
Z = Tfidf.fit_transform(X)
```

and i get

```
ValueError: not a built-in stop list: russian
```

When i use english stop words that's correct

```
Tfidf = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english' )
Z = Tfidf.fit_transform(X)
```

How to improve it?
Full traceback

```
<ipython-input-118-e787bf15d612> in <module>()
      1 Tfidf = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='russian' )
----> 2 Z = Tfidf.fit_transform(X)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
   1303             Tf-idf-weighted document-term matrix.
   1304         """
-> 1305         X = super(TfidfVectorizer, self).fit_transform(raw_documents)
   1306         self._tfidf.fit(X)
   1307         # X is already a transformed view of raw_documents so

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in fit_transform(self, raw_documents, y)
    815 
    816         vocabulary, X = self._count_vocab(raw_documents,
--> 817                                           self.fixed_vocabulary_)
    818 
    819         if self.binary:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _count_vocab(self, raw_documents, fixed_vocab)
    745             vocabulary.default_factory = vocabulary.__len__
    746 
--> 747         analyze = self.build_analyzer()
    748         j_indices = _make_int_array()
    749         indptr = _make_int_array()

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in build_analyzer(self)
    232 
    233         elif self.analyzer == 'word':
--> 234             stop_words = self.get_stop_words()
    235             tokenize = self.build_tokenizer()
    236 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in get_stop_words(self)
    215     def get_stop_words(self):
    216         """Build or fetch the effective stop words list"""
--> 217         return _check_stop_list(self.stop_words)
    218 
    219     def build_analyzer(self):

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in _check_stop_list(stop)
     88         return ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS
     89     elif isinstance(stop, six.string_types):
---> 90         raise ValueError("not a built-in stop list: %s" % stop)
     91     elif stop is None:
     92         return None

ValueError: not a built-in stop list: russian
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

could you guys read [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html) first before posting?

> stop_words : string {‘english’}, list, or None (default)
>
> If a string, it is passed to _check_stop_list and the appropriate stop list is returned. ‘english’ is currently the only supported
>   string value.
>
> If a list, that list is assumed to contain stop words, all of which will be removed from the resulting tokens. Only applies if
>   analyzer == 'word'.
>
> If None, no stop words will be used. max_df can be set to a value in the range [0.7, 1.0) to automatically detect and filter stop words
>   based on intra corpus document frequency of terms.

Answer (score 2):

There are several libraries for removing stop words that support more languages, for example [stop-words](https://pypi.org/project/stop-words/) or [snowballStemmer](https://pypi.org/project/snowballstemmer/).

Answer (score 0):

Import the following code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import text
my_stop_words = text.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS.union(["russian"])

Tfidf = sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='my_stop_words' )
Z = Tfidf.fit_transform(X)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).